# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in import Echo from 'laravel-echo' js file present in resources/js/bootstrap.js

Tags: laravel, socket.io

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in import Echo from 'laravel-echo' js file present in resources/js/bootstrap.js.

$ npm install --save socket.io-client
$ npm install --save laravel-echo
```

what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in bootstrap.js file in resources > js folder..
Please unlink this file and recreate. 
You can copy this file from internet and paste in your project.